# Why Not Work on IE browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

please i don't know why code not work on IE 11 browser , but in chrome browser work .

to check ,u just need copy and save this code as html file and open by your browser .

i need to run in IE browser. i check to much many way but can't solve it.

ie browser report me error in line 48 of this code but don't know why !

```
<!doctype html>
 <head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" charset="uft-8">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
 <style> 
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: #222;
  background: #ededed;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}


canvas {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  background: white;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
  display: block;
}
</style> 


<script>
let nouvelle,
  ancienne,
  pression;

let themeCouleur = [
  '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
  '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
  '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
  '#FF5722'
];
class Particule {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.gravite = parent.gravite;
    this.reinit();
    this.forme = round(random(0, 1));
    this.etape = 0;
    this.prise = 0;
    this.priseFacteur = random(-0.02, 0.02);
    this.multFacteur = random(0.01, 0.08);
    this.priseAngle = 0;
    this.priseVitesse = 0.05;
  }
  reinit() {

    this.position = this.parent.position.copy();
    this.position.y = random(-20, -100);
    this.position.x = random(0, width);
    this.velocite = createVector(random(-6, 6), random(-10, 2));
    this.friction = random(0.995, 0.98);
    this.taille = round(random(5, 15));
    this.moitie = this.taille / 2;
    this.couleur = color(random(themeCouleur));

  }
  dessiner() {

    this.etape = 0.5 + Math.sin(this.velocite.y * 20) * 0.5;

    this.prise = this.priseFacteur + Math.cos(this.priseAngle) * this.multFacteur;
    this.priseAngle += this.priseVitesse;
    translate(this.position.x, this.position.y);
    rotate(this.velocite.x * 2);
    scale(1, this.etape);
    noStroke();
    fill(this.couleur);

    if (this.forme === 0) {
      rect(-this.moitie, -this.moitie, this.taille, this.taille);
    } else {
      ellipse(0, 0, this.taille, this.taille);
    }

    resetMatrix();
  }
  integration() {
    this.velocite.add(this.gravite);
    this.velocite.x += this.prise;
    this.velocite.mult(this.friction);
    this.position.add(this.velocite);
    if (this.position.y > height) {
      this.reinit();
    }

    if (this.position.x < 0) {
      this.reinit();
    }
    if (this.position.x > width + 10) {
      this.reinit();
    }
  }
  rendu() {
    this.integration();
    this.dessiner();

  }
}
class SystemeDeParticules {
  constructor(nombreMax, position, gravite) {
    this.position = position.copy();
    this.nombreMax = nombreMax;
    this.gravite = createVector(0, 0.1);
    this.friction = 0.98;
    // le tableau 
    this.particules = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.nombreMax; i++) {
      this.particules.push(new Particule(this));
    }
  }
  rendu() {
    if (pression) {
      var force = p5.Vector.sub(nouvelle, ancienne);
      this.gravite.x = force.x / 20;
      this.gravite.y = force.y / 20;
    }

    this.particules.forEach(particules => particules.rendu());
  }
}
let confettis;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  frameRate(60);
  ancienne = createVector(0, 0);
  nouvelle = createVector(0, 0);
  confettis = new SystemeDeParticules(500, createVector(width / 2, -20));
}

function draw() {
  background(color("#222"));
  nouvelle.x = mouseX;
  nouvelle.y = mouseY;
  confettis.rendu();
  ancienne.x = nouvelle.x;
  ancienne.y = nouvelle.y;
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  confettis.position = createVector(width / 2, -40);
}

function mousePressed() {
  next = 0;
  pression = true;
}

function mouseReleased() {
  pression = false;
  confettis.gravite.y = 0.1;
  confettis.gravite.x = 0;
}
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks .

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What happens on IE? Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: You'd better make a jsfiddle. That would help you and the people to help you.

Comment: yes in line 48 i got error in IE but on chrome work well !!

Comment: Which line is line 49 and what is the exact error message? Don't you think that would have been important information to include in the question?

Comment: in this code line 48 , save this code as .html file and just run  !

Comment: Please paste the line

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you provide enough info instead of making other people do the work. For example, I'm on a Mac and can't run IE11 on this machine.

Comment: This question will be ever useless because it does not include the error message. Please edit it and include the error message.

Comment: The line 48 contains the class keyword which is a es6 syntax which cannot be recognized by es5 compilers like in ie11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 does not recognize this syntax for classes because ES6 spec: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Your code is in ES6 syntax. Convert it to ES5 using the below link and try.
[transpiler online](https://es6console.com/)

Comment: so is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: This answer is useless unless you include the error it adresses and mentions the syntax you are speaking of.

Comment: i put the codepen link , it seams we have problem on syntax for class, but how to fix it ?

Comment: Convert your code to es5 syntax @ChrisSermanni

Comment: THANK YOU ! THANK YOU ! THANK YOU !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple - this is because IE11 does not support EcmaScript 6 - the cool way to write JS with classes and this kind of cool stuff.
You can see browser support @ http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/